# How to implement general tree in SML?

Tags: smlnj

I am trying to come up with a datatype for a general tree. I tried writing

```
datatype 'a TREE = null | Node of 'a * 'a TREE list;
```

but it didn't work out. My idea is to create a list of child nodes for a parent node and then each of the nodes in this list will be the parent node for another lists of nodes and so on.
How can this be achieved?

Comment: What exactly "didn't work out"?

Comment: The `null` seems unnecessary - either a node has children and its child list is non-empty, or it hasn't and it's empty. Do you have a use case for it? (Making sure that no `null` children creep into the child list sounds messy.)